# Can we validate the value in a fragment of a ember data model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am currently learning ember data model. I learned that if we want to make a nested data structure in ember data, we can use ember data fragment. But are we able to validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to validate any object by using combination of [ember-changeset](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset) and [ember-changeset-validations](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset-validations/). You can also use this with fragments. Just create a changeset from your model/fragment/object whatever you use to represent entity data.